# Event::subscribe location in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am working on cleaning up my long controller methods by refactoring and using events where I can.

Unfortunately, I am not sure where or how I register an event subscriber to make my events fire.

I found two pretty helpful tutorials [vegbit](http://vegibit.com/laravel-event-listeners/) and [Culttt](http://culttt.com/2014/03/10/using-events-laravel-4/) but I'm still confused.

I have set up a dedicated EmailEventHandler Class

```
namespace Vault\Events;

use Vault\Repository\IndividualEmailRepositoryInterface as IndividualEmailRepositoryInterface;

    protected $individualEmail;

public function __construct(IndividualEmailRepositoryInterface $individualEmail)
  {
    $this->individualEmail = $individualEmail;
  }

Event::subscribe('EmailEventHandler');

class EmailEventHandler {


  public function subscribe($events)
    {
     $events->listen('email.saveIndividual', 'EmailEventHandler@saveIndividual');
    }

  public function saveIndividual($events)
    {
      $save = $this->individualEmail->store($events);
    }
}
```

With that done, I thought I would be able to access the event class with Event::fire.   Here is my controller function:

```
use Vault\Services\Mailers\UserMailer;

class ContractorController extends BaseController {

protected $mailer

    public function __construct(UserMailer $mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer
    }

    public function postIndividualEmail(){

    $file = Input::file('file');
    $subject = Input::get('subject');
    $message = Input::get('message');
    $memberString = Input::get('contractorName');

    //use mail service to send email
    $upload = $this->mail->sendIndividualEmail($memberStringer, $subject, $message, $file);
        if($upload['emailCount'] >= 1){

            //if mail has been sent, fire event
            Event::fire('email.saveIndividual', $upload);

        }

 ...the rest of code

    return Response::json($this->arrResponse);      

}
 }
```

Anyone see what I am missing?  TIA

Comment: Why is the `class EmailEventHandler` definition in the middle of the file? It should be below the `use` statement.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be that you have to subscribe your event within the `__construct` function, like this:

```
public function __construct(IndividualEmailRepositoryInterface $individualEmail)
  {
    $this->individualEmail = $individualEmail;
    Event::subscribe('EmailEventHandler');
  }
```